# Problem with login system in laravel, receiving InvalidArgumentException Action AuthController@login not defined in blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a login page in laravel using jwt and laravel views but when I insert the credential and try the login the page return "InvalidArgumentException Action AuthController@login not defined"

my routes in web.php:

```
Route::get ('/',  [AuthController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::get ('/panel',  [AuthController::class, 'getPanel']);
```

I've tryied to define route in api.php but nothing changes

Login method:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email_aziendale',  'password');
        try {
            if (!$token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                // return response()->json('credenziali errate');
                //  $errorrMSG=Lang::get('auth.credential_incorrect');
                // return CustomResponse::setFailResponse($errorrMSG, Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, []);
                return back()->with('error', 'credenziali errate');
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            //return response()->json('login fallito');
            return back()->with('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
        //return $token;
        // return CustomResponse::setSuccessResponse($token, '') . $token;

        return redirect('/panel');
    }

    public function getPanel()
    {
        return view('panel');
    }
```

my blade view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/logstyle.css') }}" />
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="/imagines/siconsLogo.png" alt="logos">
                </div>
                @if(count($errors) > 0)

                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li> {{ $error }} </li>
                @endforeach

                @endif
                <form method="POST" action="{{ action('AuthController@login') }}" >
                @csrf
                    <div class="inputs">
                        <svg class="login" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="40" viewBox="0 0 44 40">
                            <g stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-width="3.538" transform="translate(0 -1012.362)">
                                <ellipse ry="8.09" rx="8.244" cy="1022.221" cx="21.555" stroke-linecap="round" />
                                <path d="M1.858 1046.4c-.79 4.74 3.805 4.11 3.805 4.11H37.88s4.846.936 4.312-3.854c-.533-4.79-6.076-10.937-20.04-11.043-13.964-.106-19.504 6.047-20.294 10.786z" />
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                        <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="user@sincos.it">
                        <svg class="lock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="46" viewBox="0 0 44 46">
                            <g transform="translate(-28.15 -974.678)" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-width="3.509">
                                <rect ry="3.136" y="995.18" x="29.903" height="23.743" width="40.491" stroke-linecap="round" />
                                <path d="M49.386 1004.406v4.788" stroke-linecap="round" />
                                <path d="M37.073 994.83s-1.39-18.398 12.97-18.398c14.36 0 12.207 18.397 12.207 18.397" />
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                        <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-container">
                        <button class="button" type="submit" onclick="{{ route('/login') }}">
                            <div class="circle animate"></div><span class="sign-in">Sign in</span>
                            <div class="loader"></div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello @LeonardoGori `{{ action('AuthController@login') }}` in blade file direct use `{{ route('login') }}`.

Comment: @MayurPanchal already tryied return: Route [/login] not defined.

Comment: @KGG no, he has another problem, I defined route correctly but it say that is invalid

Comment: @LeonardoGori In web.php add to get a route from login like this 
`Route::get ('/login',  [AuthController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');`.

Comment: @MayurPanchal same problem, Route [/login] not defined.

Comment: Okay now don't return me any errors but login doesn't work, when I click submit button it just reload login page

Answer (score 0):

`<form method="POST" action="{{ action('AuthController@login') }}" >`

Change to

`<form method="POST" action="{{ route('name') }}" >`

in your example `name=login` (check-in web.php)

And add name attributes to inputs.

Comment: Already tryied and doesn't work

Comment: Try to run php artisan optimize.